# MySqlConnection in C# not working

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

My connection to my database is not working. It tries to load for a long time then says the connection failed. All i want to do is access the database and print out a name. I am brand new to this but here is what i have so far:

```
 string connectionstring = "uid=user;server=it.et.byu.edu;port=xxxxx;database=database;password=password;";
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring);
    connection.Open(); 
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT username FROM Users WHERE username='george'", connection);
    try
    {
        MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetString(0));
        }
        rdr.Close();
    }

       connection.Close();
```

Comment: is that host accessible from where you are? sounds like a timeout issue, perhaps a firewall is in the way?

Comment: We need more detail. What is the entire exception message? Is there any InnerException? Can you connect to the database using other tools such as MySQL Workbench?

Comment: I'll also add that you should be using `using() { }` blocks in your code to manage the lifetime of your `connection` and `cmd` objects.

Comment: Your application is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  I would strongly suggest that you research [parameterizing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your connection string and make sure you can connect/manipulate your MYSQL database if you are using XAMPP or other Mysql Tools using your credentials(uid,password).

For introduction this might help you :

[ADO.NET With MySQL and MSDE](http://www.functionx.com/mysqlnet/csharp/Lesson01.htm)

[Connection strings for MySQL](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql)

Best Regards